# Expected number of steps - shuffling a sequence

Tags: probability, random

I've been struggling with a problem a CS student friend of mine gave me a few hours ago.

Given that $P$ is an array of integers and $N$ is its size, how many minutes is the following algorithm expected to take?

---

```
    while isNotSorted(P) do
    { 
        WaitOneMinute();
        RandomShuffle(P)
    }
```

---

Obviously, this problem involves some probabilities/statistic knowledge and I have no training in those, but it doesn't feel that hard, even if I don't know how to approach it yet.

Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: This problem is similar to Expected number of tosses till first head comes up. Difference is probability of success(p) in first attempt is N! here is link to this full solution with explanation : > http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136808

Comment: As Priyanshu Jain noted: this problem is similar to [finding the expected number of tosses till first head comes up](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136808), the difference being that the probability of success in the first attempt is $\frac 1 {N!}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the integers in the array are distinct. Therefore, only one permutation of the integers corresponds to a sorted array.

Moreover, suppose you use the [*Fisher-Yates shuffle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (or anything where each permutation is equally likely). Since there are $N!$ permutations, each permutation has probability $1/N!$ of appearing.

Now, the [expected number of trials until first success](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/LengthToFirstSuccess.shtml) is $1/(1/N!)=N!$.

**Addendum:** without loss of generality, suppose the integers are $1,\ldots,M$ (otherwise you can relabel them; all that matters is their order) and let $n_i$ be the number of times integer $i$ is repeated. Therefore, $\sum_{i=1}^M n_i=N$ is the total number of integers. In this case, the correct permutation occurs with probability $\prod_{i=1}^M n_i!/N!$ so that the expected number of trials until first success is $N!/\prod_{i=1}^M n_i!$.

Comment: The integers may be indeed repeated, how would one proceed in that situation ?

Comment: Added. Intuitively, repetition decreases the expected number of shuffles required.